# How can I export a Zabbix Dashboard?

Tags: zabbix

I am trying to export my whole Zabbix configuration. I managed to export everything except the dashboard. 
I didn't find anything related to this in the Zabbix resources nor on the web.
Is there any way I can do it ?
Thank You.

Comment: vote on this feature request to add this resource: https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-5419

Answer (score 2):

1. Dump the dashboard related tables on the source Zabbix Instance:

```
mysqldump -p zabbix dashboard dashboard_user dashboard_usrgrp widget widget_field --single-transaction --no-create-info > dashboards.sql
```

2. Import the data on the destination Zabbix server:

```
mysql -p zabbix < dashboards.sql
```

This was tested on Zabbix 5.0 and assumes your database name is zabbix. Replace the DB name with your custom DB name after -p in both commands above.

Answer (score 1):

I believe we cannot export zabbix dashboard. The items that can be exported are listed here in zabbix [documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/xml_export_import). If your purpose for export is for creating a new dashboard in same zabbix instance, you can clone existing [dashboard](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/web_interface/frontend_sections/monitoring/dashboard)